# ASP.NET: Storing sessions with #temp tables to run other store procedures on

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The project I have been working on can be broken into two different stored procedures.

1. 1st Stored procedure: It is to join a few tables together into a temp table.
2. 2nd Stored procedure: This sp is edited/written based on the contents of a table that has CRUD, and it works on the temp table generated in the first stored procedure.

I am trying to execute the first stored procedure and store the temp table in a session and then run the second stored procedure manually obtain another table that uses.

-EDIT-

SP1 takes about 30s to set up a temp table by joining many tables, and I want to use the temp table from SP1 not just for SP2 but many different SPs.

I'm not sure if this is possible?

Comment: I think you can use ViewState["name"] for that.Search more for it on MS Official website or google.

Comment: Is that really the best approach? Is the performance benefit worth the additional complexity?

Comment: @Ushaphulwani but if i need to store the whole table? ViewState["name"] only stores a string?

Comment: @DaleBurrell i already have the 2 stored procedures, i just want to ensure that the connection persists and the temp table is held in the session to be run by the second sp. I assume the process shouldn't be too tedious?

Comment: But why not just call SP1 as the first action in SP2 - then you don't need to do that?

Comment: @DaleBurrell. I was going to suggest the same but then also if you want to store the table it can be stored in ViewState. Name is just the name of ViewState object with which you can access it like session.

Comment: @Ushaphulwani you can't call SP2 against data stored in ViewState though. It needs to be in the database for SP2 to work.

Comment: @DaleBurrell.. Oh yeah.. My mistake

Comment: @DaleBurrell the bottle necking sp is SP1. SP1 takes about 30s to query, SP2 takes <1s. I would need to run SP2 and other SP with the information from SP1. So the 30s overhead is the feature that causes slowness for queries

Comment: I would start by optimising SP1

Comment: @DaleBurrell It is due to the sheer amount of data for joining the tables. There tens of thousands of entries! I don't think it is possible to optimise it by much

Comment: We have hundreds of millions of rows regularly queried in under a second. Sounds like you have some schema design issues (lacking business key/foreign key indexes, covering indexes, etc.), weird join semantics, or a whole lot of scalar user-defined function operations going on.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible as the local temporary tables have scope to only current session.

You can create local and global temporary tables. Local temporary tables are visible only in the current session, and global temporary tables are visible to all sessions [Source :MSDN]

If you are trying to create this for a web application I suggest you to create Stored Procedure (which wraps both stored procedures execution) and the creation of temp table should be at the outer stored procedure. Then it will be available to both the stored procedures that are invoked from this procedure.

Going with global temporary tables is also not a reliable solution.

Comment: Further, if the #temp table is created within the 1st stored procedure then the scope is limited to that 1st stored procedure. The 2nd stored procedure, even when invoked on the same SPID (connection) will not be able to see the #temp table because it has already been disposed of by SQL Server.

Comment: Hmmm, so there is really no way to store the temp table? I thought of a few solutions to solve this issue. Run SP1 and store it as an object and then, convert it into a temp table using Dapper and then run SP2.

Comment: Two options come to mind: 1. exec SP2, which creates the #temp table, then executes SP1 to fill it, then SP2 does something with it; 2. create #temp table on the connection, exec SP1 on the same connection to fill it, exec SP2 on the same connection to do something with it. You really should be persisting this data in a schema table somewhere, though, and having a reaper process come through to clean up old data.